# Permanently indicate to Market an application should refuse upgrades?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

Some applications update frequently, (like Dolphin Browser), but to my needs the current version is clearly enough, barring a major advance of the application. Some applications (like Slacker Radio) remove earlier functionality via updates, in the interest of cleanliness or to strengthen marketing additional features to a subscriber audience. Slacker Radio specifically moved the look-ahead next artist functionality into their pay version.

So, for me, these are 2 cases for specific updates I would prefer never to perform because I am either happy, or just content. Currently I reject selecting Update-All, since they remain in the list, and update my apps one-by-one. Is there a way to tell Market/Google Play to shield them from the update list on a semi to permanent fashion to prevent them, especially to prevent inclusion in an accidental mass-update?

Comment: You may try my [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/114815/96277) if the device is rooted, and foremost, if the issue isn't resolved yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) can do what you want. (Yes, you must buy PRO. The feature is disabled in non-pro).

Once you have the app, do this:

- Open Titanium Backup Pro
- Open tab `Backup/Restore`
- Scroll to the app that you want to unlink from Market
- Long-press on the selected app
- Click `Detach from Market`

*I can't get it to work on my phone, but maybe it'll work for you.*

Comment: Geff, unfortunately this no longer works due to changes in *Google Play*. Looks like currently there is no "real way" to do that. Just work-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to changes in *Google Play*, there is no real way to hide updates from it – apart from turning them up in the *Playstore* app completely. Sounds like a contradiction, but must not necessarily be:

1. turn off update checks (and auto-updates) in the playstore app
2. get yourself the [Appbrain App Market](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps) app
3. login to the [Appbrain website](http://www.appbrain.com/) with your Google account
4. initialize the app (let it sync your installed apps with the Appbrain account created in the previous step)

Now, *this* app is responsible to inform you about updates. Once an update is signaled, you can decide to either

- install it
- skip it (this update only; so you're notified for the *next* update again)
- skip all updates for the app in question

With multiple updates pending, you can still batch-update them. Just don't be surprised updating will open the *Playstore* app again: *Appbrain* is just a different front-end to *Google Play Store*, not a separate market place :)