# How to stop Viber telling me to update in the notification bar

Tags: viber-messenger

I am running Viber on Jelly Bean 4.2.2 and when there is an update, Google Play will notify me once.  But once a day until I update the app Viber itself puts an icon in my notification top bar.  How do I stop this?

I dont want to stop knowing about updates from play, nor do I want to buy or install other apps to take care of this issue.  There should be a solution within either jelly bean or viber itself.

Comment: Why not update the app, in this case, Viber? :) Usually its best to get them updated in order to fix a glitch or an improvement to the app. Think about this - Windows notifies you to update the system, you oblige! But not with Android apps - why?

Comment: @t0mm13b I don't update sometimes because the update makes the app worse, for example Astro File Browser, I don't like the new layout so won't update it.

Comment: Similar [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/permanently-indicate-to-market-an-application-should-refuse-upgrades)

Comment: @wbogacz Nope, it's not. OP asks how to stop *Viber* from putting an additional notification (note: *Viber itself puts an icon in my notification top bar*), which is not necessarily related to the playstore (app).

Comment: @Izzy - Yep, it is similar. I didn't say or mean duplicate. It carries the same sentiment *an upgrade is not always needed or desired*. This question presents a couple more examples and reasons.

Comment: Make that ***not a duplicate*** bold uppercase :) I placed that comment to keep others from thinking it's a duplicate, and hence this question would be closed (yepp, there were already votes on that). Full ack that it is *related*, however.

Comment: I added a para to the question to indicate how the other question doesnt help?  Peanuts answer was what I was looking for.  I may decide to update when I want, but being emotionally coerced to upgrade bec of annoying messages is not the way forward.  I also find on some viber installs I need to reverify and all that.  Sometimes just cant be bothered.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [DigitalTrends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-deal-with-android-notification-spam/), when an offending notification pops up, simply long press on it and `App Info` will pop up. Tap on that and you’ll be taken straight to the app management screen where you can uncheck the `Show notifications` box and stop notifications appearing. You can also get to the app management screen by going to `Settings -> Apps` and selecting the app from there.

Unchecking the show notifications box does mean that all notifications from that app will be turned off though. As the warning states:

> If you turn off notifications for this app, you may miss important
>   alerts and updates.

Comment: It is Google Play that is sending notification for OP here. If he does as you have suggested he won't get notification for any other app.

Comment: @roxan No it's not, read the question again and the comments on it. "But once a day until I update the app Viber itself puts an icon in my notification top bar." Viber is putting the notification there. I'm aware this isn't a great solution as it also stops other notifications from Viber but it was all I could think of.

Comment: I guess you're right. Still this will prevent Viber notification as you've mentioned in your answer.

Comment: excellent - exactly what I was looking for - thanks.  Re the other comments - This is the only notification viber sends me.  I get the update notification from PLay.  Maybe I wont know if calls are coming in but thats a fight for another day!

Comment: Also the answer was Jelly bean related, not viber related, yet my jelly bean tag was edited out!!??